# Dummy Payment Method in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, html

Anybody know how to make the dummy payment and the transaction ? 
My system need the payment and the transaction when the user buying the book. I need some example of online shopping. The payment and transaction is only in localhost.

Comment: Payment gateways usually provide a sandbox environment for you to try. So you really should look at what payment gateways you are using and then look at their developer section on their website.

Comment: can u give me an example ? cause i really don't understand at all about it. really need a help.

Comment: you could use `stripe` to implement a "dummy" implementation of transactions and test your app - https://stripe.com/docs

Comment: Stripe, Braintree, PayPal, Authorize.NET, and many more - there are a bunch of them. Pick one you want to use and then look for their documentation for the sandbox.

Comment: i have lost my way. hahaha. really can't make this alone. i need an assist to do it